# JS slider image disappears when clicking Prev/Next arrow

Tags: javascript, arrays, carousel

I've tried to look for a solution for this but have failed miserably. It's my first ever time using JS (I'm trying to learn) so the possibility of my just not understanding the answers in the search results properly is quite high - sorry about that.

I am wanting a **JS carousel, generated from an array, with Prev/Next buttons** (ideally responsive etc but that'll come at a later stage), preferably **with captions underneath**. I can get the carousel to work but I end up getting a text link when I click on either Prev or Next. And I've no idea how to add the caption array underneath (I've taken out the JS for the captions for now because it was messing everything else up even further).

Relevant HTML:

```
<body onload="changePilt()">
  <span id="prev" class="arrow">&#10094;</span>
    <div class="karussell" id="karussell">
      <a href="#"><img class="karu" name="esislaid"></a>
    </div>
  <span id="next" class="arrow">&#10095;</span>
  <div class="caption">
    <h3 name="esikiri"></h3>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS, just in case:

```
.karussell {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  color: #00A7E0;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

#next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
#prev {
  left: 0;
}
.arrow:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.caption {
  text-align: center;
  color: #00A7E0;
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
.karu {
    max-width: 75%;
}
@media (max-width:767px){.karu{max-width: 95%;}}
```

And finally, the dreaded JS:

```
var i = 0;
var s = 0;
    var esileht = [];
    var aeg = 5000;

    //Image List
    esileht[0] = 'img/tooted/raamat/graafvanalinn2016.jpg';
    esileht[1] = 'img/tooted/kaart/kaart_taskus_esipool.jpg';
    esileht[2] = 'img/tooted/kaart/graafkaart_esikylg.jpg';

    //Change Image
    function changePilt (){
        document.esislaid.src = esileht[i];

        if(i < esileht.length -1){
        i++;
        } else {
        i = 0;
        }
        setTimeout("changePilt()", aeg);
    }


document.onload = function() {
}

// Left and Right arrows


    //J2rgmine
    function jargmine(){
        s = s + 1;
        s = s % esileht.length;
        return esileht [s];
    }
    //Eelmine
    function eelmine(){
        if (s === 0) {
            s = esileht.length;
        }
        s = s -1;
        return esileht[s];
    }

document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', function (e){
    document.getElementById('karussell').innerHTML = eelmine();
}
);

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('karussell').innerHTML = jargmine();
}
);
```

I'm sure the solution is dreadfully obvious, I just cannot seem to be able to figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `innerHTML` change src attribute of image

```
document.querySelector('#karussell img').src = eelmine();
```

And

```
document.querySelector('#karussell img').src = jargmine();
```

Comment: It's not working :( I can get either the slider to work OR the prev/next arrows. Any idea why?

Comment: Ignore that! I uploaded the file again and now it's working. Sorry - I can only imagine something went funky with the upload earlier and then I tried changing it and failed... Thank you for your help!